# Помогите разобраться в получении запроса из wordpress через ajax

Tags: wordpress, ajax, acf, field

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться на "пальцах", как делать ajax запросы и получать ответ в CMS wordpress при работе с произвольными полями.
У меня самая, наверное, банальная, простая обыденная задача.
Есть три поля с названием городов (Москва, Берлин, Париж).
Задача: при нажатии на любой из блоков с названием города, ниже в DIV-блоке с классом "adress" через TextContent нужно вывести соответствующий адрес, например:
ул. Красная площадь, д.1
ул. Рейхсканцелярская, д.1
ул. Эйфелева, башня 1
Данные собираю через плагин ACF , используя повторитель.
т.е. создан повторитель с полями
город:
улица:
Не понимаю логики, что-то упускаю при выполнении, но не могу понять, как происходит отправка запроса при клике на блок с названием города?
Где и когда происходит получение информации из поля?
Как ответ отправляется и как его нужно вывести?
Все что нашел в рунете по этой теме, это просто объяснение через создание плагинов, что для меня создает большую путаницу, т.к. плагины ни разу не делал. А так же примеры с использованием jquery, где не смог понять, как это переписать на чистый JS.

Буду благодарен любой помощи:
ссылками на примеры,
ссылками на учебный материал,
и т.д.
Почему хочу написать на JS? Чтобы понимать толком, как все происходит.
И jquery не всегда спасает в WP.

Comment: Вот лучшее руководство на тему создания ajax-запросов в WP: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html. Там все подробно расписано.